# Prestashop multishop: how no-index Alias subdomain

Tags: prestashop, alias, noindex

In a shop created with PS 1.7.6.1 we have created a resellers "view";
At the moment we have the mail webshop for B2C on [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) and a view with reseller.domainname.com (for B2B market)

For aspects related to SEO (duplicate product sheets etc ...), I would NOT index the entire alias of the subdomain "reseller.domainname.com"

I can NOT proceed via FTP with robots.txt file as there is no root dedicated to that alias, so it is impossible to add a command dedicated to that Url (that's not a real subdomain)

Is it possible to proceed via the HTACCESS file?
Is there any way to prevent URL path indexing reseller.domainname.com

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that both websites are sharing the same document root
(common scenario with third-level subdomain multishops ?)

In this case the solution is to edit your .htaccess like this

```
 RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [L]
```

This way you can have a different **robots.txt** for each shop named:

robots/mysite1.com.txt
robots/mysubdomain.mysite2.com.txt

Most likely you would like to add a

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

on the robots.txt of the reseller shop.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply.

Do you mean that both websites are sharing the same document root (common scenario with third-level subdomain multishops?) = Yes exactly

So, entering that command in the .htaccess file happens that:
I can create a folder /robots/ inside which I will insert a robots.txt file dedicated to each domain.
So in the root document I will have:

robots/domainname.com.txt
robots/reseller.domainname.com.txt 

is it right?

Comment: yes correct - the {HTTP_HOST} will be replaced by your domain